# How to filter list in sharepoint by another webpart(dropdown list) in C# code?

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, list

I wanna filter list in sharepoint by using dropdown list in visual studio, And view in sharepoint can't serve me in that , And i searched a lot but i didn't reach any thing

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. For example, what values would be present in the dropdown list? What list field would be filtered? Etc.

Comment: Thanks for response , Dropdown list filled with Title column of list that i wanna to filter

Comment: I know this isn't answering your question, but why do you need to do this in C#/Visual Studio? You know if you click the little black triangle next to "Title" in the view then you can filter the Title that way?

Comment: Yes i know but there are other dropdown lists depend on first dropdown list(Title) but they fill with columns from other lists so i can't use View , I wanna know how to filter sharepoint list programmatically by one dropdown list then it's so easy to filter with other dropdown lists

Comment: You absolutely could do this in Visual Studio, do you have experience developing custom SP solutions in Visual Studio? Based on what you describe, I would implement a client-based solution using jQuery and SPServices. http://spservices.codeplex.com/ You can filter multiple columns in a list view simultaneously - if the fields are present in the view. http://sharepointxperiments.wordpress.com/2009/09/18/yes-you-can-add-multiple-filters-to-a-list-view-webpart/